# Configuring Docker multi-container App with Spring Cloud Server for OpenShift Origin

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin, spring-cloud-config

Stuck with few limitations to build an effective cluster based design for a distributed app (using Docker + OpenShift Origin)

To give a brief idea about my current architecture, we have multiple war and micro-services and all these apps following common approach to read property files from external folder (outside of war).
Example: /usr/local/share/appconfigs and my app refers from classpath.

We are using token based approach to generate these property files, based on environment. These files will be available in github.

To Dockerize our apps (war & services), I am building these properties first then copying them to catalina_base to make them available in classpath in Dockerfile.

Now to make my app so flexible and run multiple instances for different environments (example: DEV, INT, PREFIX) I am considering spring-cloud-config (server).

Brief summary,

Step 1) My externalized properties are built and available in github (Example: appconfigproperties)
Step 2) One Docker container runs with spring-cloud-server-config to serve property files based on profile key
Step 3) Run Docker App (war & other services) in another container using above properties.

Now Limitations here
 I cannot use spring-cloud-config-client in my app, because it is not built on Spring-Boot. So I have left with only option that is REST based api to get properties

But I need the properties from one running container (which are served by spring-cloud-config-server), in another container App in its Dockerfile to copy to its catalina-base folder (so technically before app running).

If I want to run myty app in Dev or Int, I just need to run a container with few clicks, to make this distributed app completely configuration driven and on demand.

Appreciate your time to read and suggest possible changes to the solution if needed.

Comment: This post is worth reading https://blog.openshift.com/environment-dependent-property-management-strategies-openshift-pipelines/

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezSoria: ConfigMaps need spring-cloud-kubernetes or other libraries which will work in pattern of KV pattern, and these libraries are spring-boot solution again.

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezSoria: Indeed you are right, sorry got stuck with other config issues in the router and services.

Here is the config I have created through ConfigMap, and exposed via Environment Variable. Config file is [here](https://github.com/ashokgudise/distributed-ap/blob/master/distributed-app-clustur-up.yaml)

Comment: Glad to hear that